# oracle transpose based on column values

Tags: sql, oracle

I know transpose (or pivot) w/ sql is a common ask, but I haven't been able to get to exactly what I'm trying to do on stack/google.

In short, I want case when/then without hardcoding all possible values of a column because these values may be numerous and/or change over time.  For example,

```
id col val
1  a   65
1  b   34
1  c   25
2  a   67
2  c   22
...
```

the goal is to wind up with a single row for each distinct id, with columns for each distinct col

Easy enough when the values of col are static and small, but when there are dozens of such values hardcoding every possible clause in a case statement seems arduous.

in psuedo code, what i want to do is

```
select
for each attr in (select distinct col from table)
sum(case when col = attr then val end) as transposed_attr,
end for
from table
group by id
```

But i'm inexperienced with PL/SQL, so I don't know how to achieve this in oracle.

Advice?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Oracle?  11g introduces the pivot command...

Infact, just look here for both using PIVOT command and not:
  http://orafaq.com/wiki/PIVOT

Comment: sorry, 9i.  I don't have pivot.

Comment: @justincress - Then, as the postesd link says, you're on to the CASE/DECODE version.  And if you need to rotate 300 rows into 300 columns, then you need 300 CASE/DECODE statements.  Sorry.